# Use special characters or regular characters with BubbleChart

Tags: charts, plotting

I have a list of points I want to plot. I'm trying to use BubbleChart because I want to assign to each point a different shape.

How do I plot a BubbleChart with each point drawn with a different shape?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
BubbleChart[{{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 3}}, 
 ChartElements -> {\[EmptySquare], \[EmptyUpTriangle], \
\[EmptyCircle]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BubbleChart[{{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 3}}, 
 ChartElements -> (Graphics@Text[Style[ToString@#, FontSize->Scaled[1]]] & /@ {□, △, ○})]
```

[image]

Alternatively, turning the example from [FilledCurve >> Applications >> Text Effects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html) into a function:

```
toGraphics = Graphics[{EdgeForm[], First[First[
   ImportString[ExportString[Style[ToString@#, FontSize -> 64], "PDF"], 
       "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]}] &;

BubbleChart[{{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 3}}, 
 ChartElements -> (toGraphics /@ {□, △,  ○}), 
 ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

**Note:** the second approach works in v9. In v12 (Wolfram Cloud Front End) it produces error messages.

Comment: With the first solution the size of the shape does not change correctly. Try data values of `{{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 30}}`

Comment: Thank you @Rohit; good catch. Changed the font size specification to `Scaled[1]`.